# Preventing Spring Roo from recreating JSPx files

Tags: spring, spring-roo, jspx

I would want spring roo to stop generating jspx files for me. Certain jspx files like list.jspx is not required for my project.

I have tried deleting the file but roo will automatically regenerate the jspx files for me . Can this be done ?

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to take care of this is to adjust the @RooWebScaffold annotation:

```
@RooWebScaffold(path = "...", 
                formBackingObject = ...class, 
                delete=false, 
                update=false)
```

This will trigger the Roo shell to remove the delete and the update method from the Controller and also adjust the relevant view artifacts.